# Render error in React Native in app.js file

Tags: javascript, react-native, rendering

so I was designing some simple navbar code for my react-native app
using react-navigation and ionicons dependencies. For this, I made a separate file called maincontainer.js and used it as a tag in the main app.js file. But whenever I bundle the app and run it on my android emulator, it always gives a render error stating that:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`., 
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

Here is the code for my app.js file:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { MainContainer } from './navigation/MainContainer';

function App(){
  return(
    <MainContainer/>
     );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code for my MainContainer.js

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, TabActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
//Screens
import HistoryScreen from './screens/HistoryScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import LocationScreen from './screens/LocationScreen';
//ScreenNames
const HistoryName='HistoryScreen';
const HomeScreenName='HomeScreen';  
const LocationName='LocationScreen';

const Tab= createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function MainContainer(){
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName={HomeScreenName}
            screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({focused,color,size}) => {
                    let iconName;
                    let rn=route.name;
                    if(rn === homeName){
                        iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';
                    }
                    else if (rn === HistoryName){
                        iconName = focused ? 'history' : 'history-outline';
                    }
                    else if (rn ===  LocationName){
                        iconName = focused? 'location' : 'location-outline';
                    }
                  return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
                },
            })}
            >
            <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen}/>
            <Tab.Screen name={historyName} component={HistoryScreen}/>
            <Tab.Screen name={LocationName} component={LocationScreen}/>
            </Tab.Navigator>
            
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Please help me in the resolving the issue, thanks.

Comment: the import in app.js should be `import MainContainer  from './navigation/MainContainer';`

Comment: Cause there is .jsx file used somewhere    Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string